# Heat Equation: Let C be a circle of radius 1 and let u(θ, t) be the temperature at a point θ, at time t.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let C be a circle of radius 1 and let $u(\theta,t)$ be the temperature at a point $\theta$, at time t. To make this well-defined, we need that $u(\theta + 2\pi) = u(\theta)$.  Say $u(\theta, t)$ satisfies the heat equation $u_{t} = u_{\theta \theta}$.

Let $ E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u^{2}(\theta,t) d\theta $.

(a) Show that $E^{'}(t) \leq 0$.

(b) If the initial temperature $u(\theta,0) = 0$, show that $u(\theta,t) = 0$ for all $t \geq 0$.

Can someone check my work to see that it makes sense. In part (a) I used integration by parts and the fact that $u(\pi,t) = u(-\pi)$. Part (a) is the one that I am most worried about; mainly the statement, "Energy is constant in time." How would I prove that? or a better question would be, have I already proven that? Anyway, here is my work. Thanks in advance.

(a)

$ \frac{d}{dt} E(t) = E^{'}(t) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u^{2}(\theta, t) d\theta = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u^{2}(\theta, t)) d\theta =  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u(\theta,t)u_{t}(\theta,t) d\theta \\$

$= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u(\theta,t) u_{\theta\theta}(\theta,t)d\theta = u(\theta,t) u_{\theta}(\theta,t) |_{-\pi}^{\pi} -  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u_{\theta}(\theta,t)u_{\theta}(\theta,t) d\theta \\$

$ = u(\pi,t)u_{\theta}(\pi,t) -u(-\pi,t)u_{\theta}(-\pi,t)  - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u_{\theta}^{2}(\theta,t) d\theta \\$

$ = u(\pi,t)u_{\theta}(\pi,t) -u(\pi,t)u_{\theta}(\pi,t)  - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u_{\theta}^{2}(\theta,t) d\theta =  - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u_{\theta}^{2}(\theta,t) d\theta$

From here I can say that since this is a definite integral that is being squared, only a positive number will arise and hence be multiplied by the negative on the outside. Therefore we can only get zero or a negative number; $ E^{'}(t) \leq 0 $.

(b)

If $u(\theta,0) = 0$, then $ E(0) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u^{2}(\theta,0) d\theta = 0 $.

Since energy is constant in time, $E(t) = 0 \quad  \forall t \geq 0$.

$\therefore$ $u(\theta,t) = 0 \quad \forall t \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost correct. Note that you have proved that $E'(t)\le0$, so you can just assure that the energy is non-increasing in time. A non-incresing and non-negative (note that $E(t)\ge0$) function implies that... The conclusion is the same, you should try to be more precise with the words you use.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well thank you for checking my work. I'll try to be more careful with my words next time.